# How to use object detection API with an old version of tensorflow - v1.3.0?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I need to use tensorflow object detection API (ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco) but I have to use tensorflow 1.3.0 (mandatory due to the environment).

I have a retrained model on 1.9.0 but it's not compatible with 1.3.0:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "run_test.py", line 29, in
>   
>       tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')   File "/opt/carndcapstone/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 285, in import_graph_def
>       raise ValueError('No op named %s in defined operations.' % node.op) ValueError: No op named NonMaxSuppressionV3 in defined
>   operations.

Just wondering if it's possible to use object detection API with tensorflow 1.3.0. Didn't see a 1.3.0 release API on GitHub. Is there a way to work around?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did,

**Step 1:** Train the model using the latest available [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)

Now you have trained ckpt and other files

```
└── training
   ├── checkpoint
   ├── model.ckpt.data-XXXX-of-XXXX
   ├── model.ckpt.index
   └── model.ckpt.meta
```

**Step 2:** Now clone, previous commit of Object Detection API which is compatible with tensorflow 1.3.0 [1f34fcafc1454e0d31ab4a6cc022102a54ac0f5b](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/1f34fcafc1454e0d31ab4a6cc022102a54ac0f5b/research/object_detection)

**Step 3:** create new conda virtual environment with tf 1.4.0, and install dependencies to use object detection API in the newly cloned Object Detection Folder

**Step 4:** Activate new conda environment and just run `export_inference_graph.py` on the ckpt model trained in the first step.

The frozen graph generated is compatible with Tensorflow `1.3.0` and `1.4.0`

For more details follow [this](https://github.com/smasoudn/traffic_light_detection)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did.

For the actual training process, I followed [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/).

According to [releases](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?after=v1.5.0-rc1), Tensorflow 1.3.0. came out on August 16, 2017. 
So you will need to use the corresponding version of the [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/289a2f99a7df528f6193a5ab3ee284ff3112b731). At that time, the [Protocol Buffers v3.4.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases?after=v3.5.2) were the latest, so you need to use them as well.

You might get [`ValueError: axis = 0 not in [0, 0)`](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/issues/45#issuecomment-371480712) (I don't have it confirmed, but I suspect this error shows up when you created your TFRecords using the newer Object Detection API.) Just in case the link doesn't work, the solution is to modify your pipeline `*.config`, like so:

```
loss {
  classification_loss {
    weighted_sigmoid {
    anchorwise_output: true  #add this
    }
  }
  localization_loss {
    weighted_smooth_l1 {
    anchorwise_output: true  #add this
    }
  }
  hard_example_miner {
    num_hard_examples: 3000
    iou_threshold: 0.99
    loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
    max_negatives_per_positive: 3
    min_negatives_per_image: 0
  }
  classification_weight: 1.0
  localization_weight: 1.0
}
```